# Qt startup error: symbol lookup error: libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Font_Format

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link

First I downloaded the qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.3.run software from the qt official website.

Then I installed **qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.3.run** file in my rhel 7.4 system using ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.3.run command.

After successfully installed the qt software I ran the qtcreator from the terminal by as follows,

[root@localhost bin]# ./qtcreator
**./qtcreator: symbol lookup error: /opt/Qt5.12.3/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Font_Format**

I got the above highlighted error.
Please guide me to solve the issue.

**My System details:** 
[root@localhost bin]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 6 19:56:57 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with QT 5.13 with CentOS 7; I resolved it by running:

```
sudo yum update freetype-devel
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

On RHEL 7.4, the `freetype` package is `freetype-2.4.11-15.el7.x86_64.rpm` which defines the symbol `FT_Get_X11_Font_Format` but not `FT_Get_Font_Format`:

```
[root@localhost /]# readelf -s /lib64/libfreetype.so.6 | grep -i font_format
   406: 0000000000020960    43 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 FT_Get_X11_Font_Format
```

The [freetype API has changed](https://github.com/juj/emscripten-freetype/commit/f4d1c11faa116daad655b50828a434babbdaed2a) so that `FT_Get_X11_Font_Format` was renamed to `FT_Get_Font_Format` in [version 2.6](https://github.com/winlibs/freetype/blob/master/docs/CHANGES#LC834):

```
[root@localhost /]# readelf -s /lib64/libfreetype.so.6 | grep -i font_format
   345: 00000000000232a0    43 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 FT_Get_X11_Font_Format
   523: 0000000000023270    43 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 FT_Get_Font_Format
```

`FT_Get_X11_Font_Format` is still present for backward compatibility.

Programs that were compiled with `freetype` >= 2.6 may use the new API and, by doing this, such programs will not work with older versions of `freetype`.

You can fix this by simply updating `freetype` and/or `freetype-devel` which will upgrade to version 2.8 (as of today):

```
yum update freetype
yum update freetype-devel
```

If the response of `yum update freetype-devel` is:

> No packages marked for update

Then this means you did not install `freetype-devel`, thus you only need to update `freetype`.

If you cannot use `yum`, you may download [freetype-2.8](http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/freetype-2.8-12.el7.x86_64.rpm) and upgrade it manually:

```
rpm -Uvh freetype-2.8-12.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: thank you. that was causing teamviewer to fail to start on oracle linux 7. updating freetype fixed it