# Qt startup error: symbol lookup error: /lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 : undefined symbol : FT_Get_Font_Format

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, symbolic-link

When I run the following python code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.arange(3)
plt.pyplot(a, a)
plt.show
```

The machine print:

```
[test001@login01 ~]$ python3 draw.py
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-test001'
python3: symbol lookup error: /beegfs/home/test001/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/..//lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Font_Format
```

I have tried the way of [Qt startup error: symbol lookup error: libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Font_Format](https://superuser.com/questions/1451321/qt-startup-error-symbol-lookup-error-libqt5xcbqpa-so-5-undefined-symbol-ft-g/1767924?noredirect=1#comment2751992_1767924) , but it doesn't work. When I use

```
[test001@login01 ~]$ readelf -s /lib64/libfreetype.so.6 | grep -i font_format
   406: 0000000000020960    43 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 FT_Get_X11_Font_Format
```

freetype-2.8, 2.10, 2.12 are also test, the output is the same, it can't find FT_Get_Font_Format

In this case, what should I do?

```
Centos version: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
Qt5 version: 5.15.2
PyQt5 version: 5.15.9
```

Comment: It certainly more suitable at https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Your PyQt uses the FreeType function [FT_Get_Font_Format](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-font_formats.html). This is good.

But your freetype lib libfreetype.so.6 only provides **FT_Get_X11_Font_Format**. This is bad because this function is deprecated.

I checked my own system and I have the same file libfreetype.so.6 providing the newer FT_Get_Font_Format function. I have freetype 6.17.4.

So you must have a freetype version which is:

```
6 <= version < 6.17.4
```

Install all updates on your OS. If your OS does not offer a newer freetype lib then simply downgrade matplotlib.

Run this to uninstall your current matplotlib:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
```

Run this to list all available matplotlib versions:

```
pip index versions matplotlib
```

Run this to install a specific version of matplotlib:

```
pip install matplotlib==3.6.2
```

You can start with 3.6.2 and if this doesn't work uninstall it and go one version down to 3.6.1. Do this until your script runs finely.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the reason is freetype of `freetype-2.8`, `freetype-2.10` haven't compile completely. The version is still using `freetype-2.4` provided by `yum install freetype`.

I use the following links, then the `FT_GET_Font_Format` function can be found.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/zlib/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/libpng/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=software/freetype/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```